# NSUserDefaults returns previous result

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nsuserdefaults

I have a tableView where I can select a ship from a list, and when I tap it I want the information to pop up on another screen. The way I am currently doing this is:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{

cargoShips* ship=[boatsForOwner objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
UITableViewCell *cell = [self.boatsTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"boatInfoSegue" sender:cell];




NSString *nameString = ship.name;
NSString *sizeString = ship.size;


NSUserDefaults *shipName = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[shipName setObject:nameString forKey:@"globalName"];
[shipName synchronize];
NSUserDefaults *shipSize = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[shipSize setObject:sizeString forKey:@"globalSize"];
[shipSize synchronize];
[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
```

And to load it back into text (in another file)

```
 NSString *getName = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
                     objectForKey:@"globalName"];
NSString *getSize = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
                     objectForKey:@"globalSize"];

shipNameText.text = getName;
shipSizeText.text = getSize;
```

Now , this works great, except for the fact that it does not return the cell I selected to get to the infoView, but the previous selected object. So if I select the first object on the list, it returns null, the next item i select gets the result I should have had for the first object and so on.

What did I do wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: You should know that `shipName` and `shipSize` are the same object.

Comment: @NikolaKirev Sorry, what do you mean? They return different values

Comment: Are you sure that the value is being read *after* it is written? Try setting some breakpoints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NSUserDefaults` is tool for saving settings, not for transferring object.
If I were you I made it this way:

```
#pragma mark - Segue
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue
                 sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"boatInfoSegue"]) {

        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        CargoShip *ship = boatsForOwner[indexPath.row];

        BoatViewController *vc = (BoatViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
        vc.ship = ship;      
    }
}
```

Class names should be capitalized, that's why I wrote `CargoShip`

Comment: Yes, I thought of that, but I could not find any better alternatives for transferring stuff between views so I just stuck to UserDefaults. How would I then access this data in my target view?

Comment: In target view you read your data in viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear methods from property 'ship'.

Comment: In 'BoatViewController' you put into interface @property(nonatomic) CargoShip *ship;

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see in your code. your problem is that you first perform the seque and then update the values in the `NSUserDefaults` move this line `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"boatInfoSegue" sender:cell];` to the end of the method.
This should make it work, but you need to refactor you code.

Comment: Refactor? What does that mean? And moved segue to the bottom of the code block, still the same issue.